# Remove user selected words from a list of words

Tags: javascript, input

I'd like to have an input area that a user can specify a list of words or strings(such as "www.", ".com", "Random Word" ) that will be filtered out of a list of words also submitted by the user. I've seen the use of .map and .replace but i'm not sure how to use the input submitted by someone.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should add an extract of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The following will search the `data` array for each of the words in the text field (`searchTerm`).  It's currently separating the term on space, but you could easily change that to a comma or any other number of ways of splitting it up, including using a regex to allow for multiple word search terms (i.e. "Random Word").  Anything in the search term will be filtered from the array into the `result` variable.  The search is case sensitive (also easy to change).

```js
var data = [ 'Hello', 'World' ];

function buttonClicked() {
    var element;
    element = document.getElementById('searchTerm');
    var searchTerms = element.value.split(' ');
    var result = data.filter(
        e => -1 == searchTerms.indexOf(e)
    );
    console.log(result);
}

function init() {
    var element;
    element = document.getElementById('button');
    element.addEventListener('click',buttonClicked,false);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input id='searchTerm' type='text'>
    <input id='button' type='button'>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll let give you an update once I get it working with my code.